# Accessing .pfx file on hololens

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, mqtt, x509, hololens

I am building a Hololens Unity App and I am trying to load in connection certification files for a server I connect to in my app. There is a .crt and a .pfx file located at the Assets/StreamingAssets folder.

On the unity editor and when running the app on unity, the files are read correctly and the connection works.

Here is the Code:

```
X509Certificate caCert = new X509Certificate(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/a.crt");
UnityEngine.Debug.Log(caCert + "TRUE");

X509Certificate2 clientCert = new X509Certificate2(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/b.pfx");     
UnityEngine.Debug.Log(clientCert + "TRUE");

MqttClient client = new MqttClient(broker, 8883, true, caCert, clientCert, MqttSslProtocols.TLSv1_2, MyRemoteCertificateValidationCallback);
```

My problem is that when I deploy this to thew hololens, ***I am unable to access the .pfx file*** and it does not appear to be deployed onto the hololens saying that the file is not found (but the .crt file and the rest of the folder are there...).

*Another issue I have:*
I have also manually entered the certifications into the hololens' c: drive and they show up in its file explorer. I do not know how to access them, since that would be an easier workaround if I could just find the location of the file on the hololens drive itself and load it in from my app.

If anyone has experience with loading in files onto hololens unity-based applications and can help me with loading in the files while using the application on the hololens2, I would appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 0):

Since HoloLens APP is a UWP APP, so make sure you use backslashes ()  as a path separator character. And the best practice is to use [`Path.Combine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=net-5.0) instead of constructing paths yourself. It will take care of all the platform specific prefixes, appendices, delimiters, slashes, backslashes etc.

```
X509Certificate caCert = new X509Certificate(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/a.crt");
```

=>

```
X509Certificate caCert = new X509Certificate(Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "a.crt"));
```